# Скрыть повторы через JQuery

Tags: jquery, повторы

http://jsfiddle.net/72bEQ/

Как скрыть повторные классы и оставить только один из них? Т.е нужно оставить:

```
<div class="test1">test1</div>
<div class="test5">test5</div>
<div class="test6">test6</div>
<div class="test8">test8</div>
```

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, ух ты, работает! Превратите свой комментарий в ответ, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сами пробовали делать?

```
$("div").each(function(i,itm){
  $('.'+itm.className).not(":first").hide();
});
```